# SubscriptionNotFound: The subscription 'resourceGroups' could not be found

Tags: c#, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to follow the [Resource group authenticate service principal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/) to be able to access some resource manager stuff. But when trying to do anything, I get the following error:

> SubscriptionNotFound: The subscription 'resourceGroups' could not be found.

Using the C# code in the article to get an access token, and then calling the follow methods:

```
    var dnsClient = new DnsManagementClient(new Microsoft.Azure.TokenCloudCredentials(result.AccessToken));

    var zone = dnsClient.Zones.CreateOrUpdate("someresourcegroup", "mydomain.com", new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Dns.Models.ZoneCreateOrUpdateParameters {
            IfNoneMatch = "*",
            Zone = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Dns.Models.Zone {
                Name = "mydomain.com",
                Location = "northeurope"
            }
        });
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I've created a service principal as a Contributor, so permissions shouldn't be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says **The subscription 'resourceGroups' could not be found**, please try specify your subscriptionid when creating the **TokenCloudCredentials** object.

```
var dnsClient = new DnsManagementClient(new Microsoft.Azure.TokenCloudCredentials("your_subscriptionid", result.AccessToken));
```

Tested from my side and it works.

Comment: Thank you, weird error message, but great! Now I'm getting something else, but at least this new one makes sense ;)

Comment: @SteenTøttrup would you mind share the new problem with me? I'd like to help you investigate it.

Comment: Already posted and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35081852/azure-badrequest-the-body-of-the-request-is-empty-or-does-not-have-the-expecte

Comment: @SteenTøttrup Thanks Steen for sharing with me :)