# Azure, BadRequest: The body of the request is empty or does not have the expected content

Tags: c#, azure, azure-resource-manager

This started out as a [SubscriptionNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080712/azure-missingregistrationforlocation-the-subscription-is-not-registered-for-th) error.

Then I ended up with a [MissingRegistrationForLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080712/azure-missingregistrationforlocation-the-subscription-is-not-registered-for-th) error.

And now I'm here.

Same code:

```
var dnsClient = new DnsManagementClient(new Microsoft.Azure.TokenCloudCredentials(result.AccessToken));

var zone = dnsClient.Zones.CreateOrUpdate("someresourcegroup", "mydomain.com", new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Dns.Models.ZoneCreateOrUpdateParameters {
    IfNoneMatch = "*",
    Zone = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Dns.Models.Zone {
        Name = "mydomain.com",
        Location = "global"
    }
});
```

And this bug:

> BadRequest: The body of the request is empty or does not have the expected content.

The other 2 errors makes sense, but this one seems a bit like a dead-end.

What Am I doing wrong this time around?

Comment: Can you trace the request through Fiddler and post the request body?

Comment: I can try, I've never worked with Fiddler and Azure before, so not sure what it is I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your code and include `Properties`:

```
        var zone = dnsClient.Zones.CreateOrUpdate("someresourcegroup", "mydomain.com", new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Dns.Models.ZoneCreateOrUpdateParameters
        {
            IfNoneMatch = "*",
            Zone = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Dns.Models.Zone
            {
                Name = "mydomain.com",
                Location = "global",
                Properties = new ZoneProperties()//Add this line!
            }
        });
```

That should take care of the problem.

Comment: Thank you, you have saved me!